# How can I update multiple rows at once while avoiding problems with unique keys?

Tags: mysql

I have the following (simplified) database table that represents teams in a tournament. Each team belongs to a pool and has a rank (1st, 2nd, etc) in that pool.

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pool_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rank` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pool_id_rank_idx` (`pool_id`,`rank`),
)
```

The unique key is there because a single pool cannot have two teams with the same rank.

When teams play each other, their ranks change and I need to update them. I'd like to be able to update all the ranks in one query, but I cannot figure out a way to do it that doesn't sometimes cause a "duplicate entry" error. Here's an example of a situation that causes this problem:

Two teams (A and B) are ranked 1 and 2 respectively in a pool. They play each other and B beats A. Now I need to switch their ranks. The query I'm using is something like this:

```
UPDATE team 
SET rank = CASE id WHEN idA THEN 2 WHEN idB THEN 1 END 
WHERE id IN (idA,idB);
```

*idA and idB are the ids of the corresponding teams*

This seems like it should work nicely, but I get this error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'pool_id_rank_idx'
```

I think this happens because MySQL checks the unique keys after each row is changed.

**Is there any way to postpone the unique key check until after all the changes are done?**

Answer (score 0):

Rank is dynamic value, why have you added to unique key? Or you mean it's not possible two similar rank values to be for one pool?

When you update data, there are two similar pool_id, rank pairs appear - that's why.

Remove Unique Key:

`ALTER TABLE team DROP INDEX pool_id_rank_idx`

Comment: I do mean that it's not possible for two teams in one pool to have the same rank. But the ranks can change, so I'd like to change them all simultaneously.

Comment: When competition is started, each team already have rank value != 0?